# Android SQLITE, unable to open database in Marshmallow only

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I built an app. (The app can save favourite items using **SQLite Database**). I tried running it on Android Nougat and there is no error. When I tried running it on Android Marshmallow, the app won't open (Force close) and when I check the error it says unable to open database. After that, I tried running it on Android Lollipop and there is no error found.

I trace the error and found on the Marshmallow, the database is not created. (I used DB debugger to check the DB). I already add these user permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and nothing happened. Anyone else knows about this??

**NEW EDIT
this is the syntax to check if the db already created or not

```
public DataHeper(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.mContext = context;
        databasePath = "data/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/databases/data.sqlite";
        databaseFile = new File(databasePath);
        if(!databaseFile.exists())
            try {
                deployDataBase(databaseName, databasePath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }



    public int getTotalQuotesNoFilter(){
            int i =0;
            String query="";
            Cursor  cursor;
            //This is the line that produce error (On Marshmallow only).
            //I trace it and found out the db not created, thats why opendatabase produce error
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                query = "SELECT count(quotes._id) FROM quotes;";
                WriteLog.d("ThangTB", "query: "+query);
                try {
                    cursor =  database.rawQuery(query, null);   
                    if (cursor != null){
                        boolean bool = cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int j = cursor.getInt(0);
                        i = j;
                     }

                    if (cursor!=null) {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }finally{
                    database.close();
                }

            return i;

        }
```

Comment: maybe you need runtime permissions please check this out https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Can you share code how do you create database?

Comment: @EugenMartynov hi eugen, i already add the syntax above :)

Comment: What does `deployDatabase()` method is doing? Why not just to have database in internal/sandox app folder?

Answer (score 2):

SQLite Db needs no user permission. So I guess there is some other issue. Post your code.

Comment: hm i think so too, because it only happen in marsmallow.
i already post my code above :)

Comment: Try using SQLiteOpenHelper class instead. Derive your own class and override the methods. Like - public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {....}. You can find examples if you search. Much easier.

Answer (score 1):

From Android M onwards, permissions needs to obtained from User while he/she is using the app, solely mentioning in Manifest wont do.

It is super easy to implement it using this library.

https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions

Comment: Thankyou for the fast response :)

i'll try ur suggestion (Y)
but im abit confused here, the thing is when i compile it on Android 7(Nougat) and any other android except Marsmallow, the app run normal, no error found. no need for permission either (except for the one in the manifest file)
only on marsmallow the error showed up, and you said from android M onwards need permission, shouldnt nougat get the error aswell?

Comment: Pretty Sure its M onwards , not sure why N is working, can you comment if the permission fixes this?

Answer (score 0):

From Marshmallow you need to request permission from user at run time, I also had the same problem check this link, it will help you. 
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/